# How to find out what is this process for?

Tags: linux, process, top

I have this 'java' process running for 3 hours ( I guess ). I didn't see it before and I wonder how could I find out where it's coming from?

Here is a screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

EDIT: ok I figured it out, it's a freenet stuff I installed few days ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What does a

```
ps  -p 1983  -f   # 1983 being the PID your screenshot shows
```

tell you about it?

Comment: thanks for response :) says:`00:06:42 java -Dnetworkaddress.cache.ttl=`

Comment: What about its parent PID, the third column in the ps output?  Looked that one up?

Answer (score 1):

Run [htop](http://htop.sourceforge.net/). It's like top, only better. In particular, htop shows the full command line, and you can scroll horizontally to see more of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also run `pstree` from the `psmisc` package to view a given PID and all its parents, all the way back to `init` or PID 1.  e.g.

```
pstree -s -p 1983
```

You can use pstree's `-A` option for ASCII line-drawing chars rather than terminal-specific (e.g. ANSI/vt100/xterm/linux) line-drawing chars.

e.g. an example from my system:

```
$ pstree -A -s -p 9879 
init(1)---screen(13578)---bash(13642)---mutt(9879)
```

If it's somehow not in your distro, `psmisc` is at http://psmisc.sf.net/

Answer (score 0):

My personal favorite is `ps -wwwaux|grep java|grep -v grep`.

You can also toggle the top-command-line (i.e. show parameters of the processes in top) by pressing `c` in top.